# Is there an environment variable in csh to modify PS2?

Tags: command-line, tcsh, csh

Is there an environment variable in CSH to change the `PS2` like in `bash` and `sh`?

For example:

```
$PS2 = "hi"
```

I tried it but it doesn't work in `csh`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're using `tcsh`, which has `prompt2` (not available in the original `csh`, AFAIK almost all of all versions of `csh` are `tcsh` these days).

From [the manpage](http://www.tcsh.org/tcsh.html/Special_shell_variables.html), section *"Special shell variables"*:

> prompt2 (+)
>   The string with which to prompt in while and foreach loops and after lines ending in `\'. The same format sequences may be used as in prompt (q.v.); note the variable meaning of`%R'. Set by default to `%R? ' in interactive shells.

It's not an environment variable, you can just use `set`:

```
% set prompt2 = 'x> '
% while 1
x>
```