# What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I enter single quote `'` in terminal it goes to some other mode, and commands don't execute. What is this mode and when do we use it?

```
root@sai:~# '
> ls
> '
ls
: command not found
root@sai:~#
```

Comment: and why are you running as root?

Comment: Your terminal is in the same mode as before - your **shell** is in a different mode (waiting for the completion of a string with another `'`)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Effectively, the shell asks for a **complete command/expression**, and for that reason is displaying the `PS2` prompt string.

From `man bash`:

> PROMPTING
>
> When executing interactively, bash displays the
>      primary prompt PS1 when it is ready to  read  a
>      command,  and  **the secondary prompt PS2 when it
>      needs more input to complete a  command.**

And a little before that:

> ```
>   PS2    The value of this parameter is  expanded
>           as  with  PS1  and used as the secondary
>           prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.
> ```

Thus, as you may guess from reading the documentation, shells have multiple prompts with different purposes. The `PS1` prompt is your `root@sai:~#` string, which shows up normally when you enter commands. `>` is the `PS2` prompt. There's others, too: `PS3` for `select` command block and `PS4` for debugging with `set -x` command. In this case we're more interested in `PS2`.

There are many ways in which shell may show the `PS2` prompt (and where completing a command on a new line might be necessary). The same prompt is used when you perform `here-doc` redirection (where a command is considered complete when you see the terminating string, in this example, `EOF`):

```
$ cat <<EOF
> line one
> line two
> EOF
line one
line two
```

Very often continuation of a lengthy command can be done by adding `\` and immediate(!) newline, which will cause the same prompt to appear:

```
$ echo Hello\
> World
HelloWorld

$ echo 'Hello\                                                                                                           
> World'
Hello\
World
```

When pipes, logic operators, or special keywords appear on command-line before newline, the command also is considered incomplete until all final statements are entered:

```
$ echo Hello World | 
> wc -l
1

$ echo Hello World &&                                                                                                    
> echo "!"
Hello World
!

$ for i in $(seq 1 3); do
> echo "$i"
> done
1
2
3 

$ if [ -f /etc/passwd ]
> then
>     echo "YES"
> fi
YES
```

In your particular case, a single quote implies literal interpretation of what is between the single quotes. Thus, as Zanna pointed out, you are entering a command that consists of newline+`ls`+newline. Such an executable filename cannot be found (and typically command filenames should consist of only alphanumeric characters, plus underscores, dashes, and dots). Although it is indeed possible to have filenames that contain special characters in them, it is always avoided.

**NOTE**: such behavior as shown in your example is specific to Bourne-like shells, including `bash`, `dash` (on Ubuntu it is symlinked to `/bin/sh`), `ksh`, and `mksh`. `csh` and its derivatives do not behave in such way:

```
$ tcsh                                                    
eagle:~> '
Unmatched '.
eagle:~> csh
% '
Unmatched '.
%
```

However, in interactive mode, `csh` will still raise `?` as [prompt2](https://askubuntu.com/a/572433/295286) when more input is required:

```
$ csh
% foreach n ( 1 2 3 )
? echo $n
? end
1
2
3
```

#### See also:

- [In which situations are PS2, PS3, PS4 used as the prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193659/85039)
- [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/678919#678919)
- [What does > mean in the terminal!](https://askubuntu.com/q/690306/295286)
- [Unable to enter new commands in terminal — stuck with “>”](https://askubuntu.com/q/836634/295286)
- [What is the effect of a lone backtick at the end of a command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345006/85039)

Comment: The link `What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?` is offline/wrong.

Comment: @Tico Thanks fixed. The answer was written with internet speed of milli-turtles per second, which resulted only in partially copied link. Fixed now

Comment: Meanwhile, zsh is kind enough to actually tell you what it is waiting for, which is occasionally useful if you thought your command was valid but forgot to escape something.

Answer (score 32):

The shell is just waiting for the closing quote. When you enter it, it will do exactly what it usually does, and attempt to execute the command entered.

Quotes cause the shell not to interpret special characters, meaning that expansions are not performed. Single quotes suppress all interpretation of special characters completely. Normally a newline separates commands, but here you have included the newlines as part of the command by quoting them.

Since there is no such command as `<newline>ls<newline>`, it is not found.