# Bash CLI: Restore previously typed command after changing it

Tags: command-line, bash

This strange (to me) behaviour has bamboozled me for years.

In bash, one can press up to refer to the previous command. Say then I accidentally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and I wish to restore the previous command, but it seems to be gone. If I clear the command, and try again, it's still gone from the history.

E.g.

1. Let's say I run the following command:

   ```bsh
   $ ls /etc/sudoers.d/
   10_at-export  010_pi-nopasswd  010_proxy  README
   ```
2. Now press <kbd>Up</kbd>:

   ```bsh
   $ ls /etc/sudoers.d/
   ```
3. Now press <kbd>Up</kbd> then <kbd>Backspace</kbd> a few times:

   ```bsh
   $ ls
   ```

Now how to return to `ls /etc/sudoers.d/` from here?

For a long command, I resort to mouse copying and pasting of the above command #mouseisuncool.

Comment: "If I press cancel and try again, it's still gone from the history." ... I don't see that behaviour  (assuming you mean Ctrl-C by "cancel")

Comment: @muru CTRL-C is perfect! I corrected my question, by cancel I meant deleting the command (CTRL-U, CTRL-K).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> is the readline key-bind for exactly what you're looking for.
In the [readline section of the bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#READLINE):

> `revert-line` (M-r)
> Undo all changes made to this line.  This is like
> executing the `undo` command enough times to return the line
> to its initial state.

You can use this even if you've up or down arrowed away from a history item and then come back to it again.

(M stands for Meta.  On a normal keyboad / X11 / terminal setup, your Alt key will work as a "meta" for your terminal.  Or equivalently you can manually press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before hitting another key to apply the same thing, if your terminal isn't set up nicely enough for alt to work.)

The `undo` command is bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd>, and it will undo the previous keystroke.

For control-w (`unix-word-rubout` (C-w)), you can also just paste back the data with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> (`yank`), like in Emacs.  Similarly for `backward-kill-word` (M-Rubout, which on a normal keyboard / terminal / X11 config is Alt+Backspace or Escape+Backspace), the killed text goes into the kill ring where you can yank it.  (After a C-y, M-y cycles through the kill ring so you can still get at older kills.)

There are many handy line-editing commands, but the list of all available is huge and overwhelming.  I definitely don't know most of them.  Being able to move the cursor around by whole "words" at a time with ctrl+arrows or M-b / M-f, and kill forwards/backwards words (and yank) is enough most of the time.  ([I mentioned some of those in another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199854/why-are-there-backslash-line-breaks-on-this-apt-install-command/1200079#1200079))

---

> If I press cancel and try again, it's still gone from the history.

**That's not how Bash works if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>**

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ echo ^C                # up arrow, C-w, C-c
$ echo foo               # up arrow recalls the pristine command
foo

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)     # I'm on Arch Linux
```

Also, running the shortened command will revert the history changes and make a new entry.

(There's also a `.inputrc` setting you could use, `revert-all-at-newline`, that makes submitting a command revert *all* changes to all other history entries.)

Comment: Sorry I corrected my answer, by cancel I meant deleting the command (CTRL-U, CTRL-K). CTRL+C is perfect. My wording was very poor. CTRL+C seems like the answer. I tried ALT-R, ESC+r, ESC then r, none of them work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 standard terminal (althought it does seem like a great command).

Comment: @run_the_race: ESC + r is escape *then* r.  ESC isn't a modifier like shift or alt, that's what I was trying to indicate with `+` with spaces instead of `-`.  If you recall a command, edit it (adding and/or removing text) without pressing enter, then hit escape then r (not shift-R), it should revert to whatever command was in the history before you started editing.  Just like holding down `ctrl-/` for a while.  Anyway, you should accept one of the answers, whichever you think is best for future readers, and/or which you found most useful; use the checkmark under the vote arrows.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt know there was a different between `-` and `+` in hotkeys, I tried ALT-R and ESC-R, neither worked. If they did I think that would be ideal, otherwise CTRL-C is to me the best answer. I would accept this answer but the first 50% does not seem to work. Does ALT-R work for you? What version Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @run_the_race: I currently use Arch GNU/Linux as shown in my sample output, but all of this works identically on my old Ubuntu 15.10 system, and even back to bash 3 on an ancient Debian system.  And yes, I routinely use all of the keybinds I mentioned, I'm not just copying from the man page.  My current desktop is KDE, with Konsole as my terminal emulator, but this worked in gnome-terminal.  And works from PuTTY on Windows, although in that case sometimes alt is broken so I have to hit escape then r in that case.

Comment: @run_the_race:  If you're using classic XTerm, in the ctrl+left-click menu there's a "meta sends escape" option which may be necessary.  It's remotely possible some Ubuntu 20.04 config broke some of these keybinds, either in a `.inputrc` for bash, or a terminal emulator, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I was always too lazy to read the entire readline section in `man bash` (it's huge!) and didn't know about Alt-R. I always used the "Enter on empty line" method I described in my answer. But this is far better and exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: @raj: Thanks.  Yeah, I was more keen when I first started using GNU/Linux, but even then I never went through that section of the man page to consider every single keybind.  I forget how I learned about M-r revert; maybe by wondering if there was a keybind for it and searching (google or man page), or a mention in a Linux Journal article, or something.  Or perhaps fat fingering it instead of C-r (reverse-search history).  Or sometimes searching the man page for something else (e.g. array / expansion syntax or shopt stuff), a search takes me into this part and I notice something.

Comment: @raj: I've picked up a new bash keybind every few years, and I've been using GNU/Linux on my desktop with bash as my shell for about 25 years now.  Having invested the time to get good at it, I have near zero interest in switching to clicking on stuff instead of chaining commands together.  Using a phone feels like a very limited toy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am using GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 (comes with Ubuntu 20.04). I think escape codes work cause I use VIM and ALT-SOMEKEY, which does escape insert mode. then run the function for SOMEKEY. I accepted the answer since it seems to work for others, and you have the section on CTRL-C, thank you for the insightful answer!

Answer (score 10):

Once you have messed up with the command, delete the rest of it and just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (all this without using up- or down-arrow) The shell will "execute" the empty line and create a new entry in command history instead of changing the old one, so after this, you will be able to return to the deleted command normally with up-arrow.

Try this:

1. Type `nosuchcommand` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Of course you will get a "command not found" message ;)
3. Press up-arrow to return to `nosuchcommand` command and delete it in any way you want
4. Just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The shell will "execute" the empty line and another prompt will appear.
5. Press up-arrow and the `nosuchcommand` command reappears :)

Comment: Slightly dangerous: If say the command was `rm ~/importfile.conf.bak` and one backscapes 4 times then presses enter by reflex when one realises one wishes to change a command.

Comment: @run_the_race Therefore I wrote that you should delete the rest of the command completely before pressing Enter.
As far as I know, that's the only simple way to achieve what you wanted. I have been doing this for years :)

Comment: What advantage does this have over pressing control-C to cancel the command entirely (and still revert history edits to this history entry so you can recall it again)?  Your step-by-step walk-through of how history works for this example is good, but would be much better IMO if you replace your ctrl-a + ctrl-k + Enter (or whatever line kill method you like) with Control-C

Comment: @PeterCordes Probably no advantage. It's just the method I'm used to :)

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing indeed by up arrowing is directly editing your command history. Thus, recalling the command `ls /etc/sudoers.d/` and editing it effectively changes that history item.

To effectively "copy" the command and modify the copy rather than the history item, use your mouse (...no, joking!!)

**Default bash feature**

To effectively "copy" the command and modify the copy rather than the history item, use the reversed search feature, i.e. "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. Type two or three letters, e.g. `sud` until you see the command. If there are multiple matches in your history, you can continue hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> until the command you wish appears, or type a few more letters.

Once you see the command, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Left</kbd> arrow keys will "copy" the command to your prompt. That will, after execution, become another history item.

**Power tip: Fuzzy finder**

Power users can install fuzzy find. It includes a replacement for the default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, where matching commands from the history appear in a list. <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the desired line "copies" it at the prompt.

Comment: Hitting any cursor-movement key during a control-r `reverse-search-history` doesn't actually *copy* the history entry.  At that point you're editing that history entry directly on your prompt, and it only gets reverted if you control-c, or hit return to run the edited command.  (e.g. if you mess it up, then up/down arrow or `alt->` (`end-of-history`) and run some other command, then go back to that edited history entry, it will still be edited.  It stays modified unless/until you go back to it and `alt-r` to revert all changes to it, or `ctrl-/` to undo changes one at a time,

Comment: I'm used to zsh and `history-beginning-search-backward` mapped to <kbd>Up</kbd>, which seems to do everything up, ctrl+r and ctrl+a do in bash. What's the advantage of having to use ctrl+r and ctrl+a instead?

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> will restore the removed text.

Comment: Thanks, although it works, it only works in the exact case of pressing CTRL+W, the heart of the issue is bring back the command (not just that specific case).

Comment: You can try pressing/holding down CTRL+_    This will replace the last deleted text (undo feature)

Comment: @Maik test the stepwise scenario that run_the_race posted. It does not work like that.

Comment: @vanadium do you mean my answer or my comment? the original question was edited and only asked about the CTRL+W command. And does CTRL+_ not work in the edited question? I tried it and it was working for me (albeit replacing a character at a time --- your answer is much more intuitive :) )

Comment: Your answer: it is valid for what was said in the second paragraph, but not in general.  Ctrl+W (and likely other combination) appear to place text in a buffer, that then can be "yanked" back with CTrl+Y. The stepwise scenario was there in the original question, but, I agree, that second paragraph only focusing on Ctrl+W is confusing here.

Answer (score 1):

**Undo step by step**: I sometimes make a mistake and want to fix only the last change or last couple of changes. Recently I discovered <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. That performs "undo" step by step until you get to the original command or empty line if you started from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can always look up a previously used command using the `history` command, then use:

`!(number of the command in the history):s/(what you wish to correct)/(your correction)/`

As an example, given this command from the history:

```
  995  brave_browser
```

If I want to replace the underscore with the hyphen, because the correct command is `brave-browser`, I would use:

```
!995:s/_/-/
```

More info: https://ss64.com/bash/history.html