# How to escape to add additional lines in bash commands?

Tags: command-line, bash

When I run a bash program, it asks for input. Now I have to give a paragraph with newlines as input to the function.

In terminal whenever I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it's going to next part of program. Which character should I use for escaping line - if I type `\n` it's taking the string `\n` as an input.

Comment: You should be able to use backslash characters to escape the literal newlines - see this related topic [Terminal shows > after entering \ .](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107974/178692)

Comment: Can you include the Bash script? It will help to know how it tries to read your multiline input, and how we can provide such input in a way that it will interpret it as intended

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to transform `\n` to actual newlines, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Prints "Please enter a message",  and reads input
read -rep $'Please enter a message:\n' message

# Transforms any occurences of "\n" and replace them with newline
message=$(printf "${message}" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g')

# Prints the transformed string
echo "$message"
```

Result:

```
Please enter a message:
Paragraph\nMessage
Paragraph
Message
```

*Inspired by [this existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527170/how-to-read-input-lines-with-newline-characters-from-command-line) on Unix & Linux.*