# Terminal input changes on SOME incorrect commands

Tags: command-line

I enter a command like this one:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +`
```

The ` on the end breaks the command and the next fields are:

```
>
>
>
```

etc. There I can write whatever I want and quitting this happens only through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

My question is: what are those **>** that I am getting to? I am not finding any information on why this is happening and what is its purpose.

Comment: See [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)