# question regarding command line syntax

Tags: command-line, bash

recently I wanted to calculate the time difference of two dates (in days) using a one-liner in bash. So I wanted to use the command

```
echo $((($(date +%s --date "2018-01-08")-$(date +%s --date "1999-12-28"))/(3600*24))) days
```

which would yield "6586 days".

Out of clumsiness I forgot to type the finishing inverted commas in the first date entry:[ date +%s --date "2018-01-08 ]

I got this output:

```
echo $((($(date +%s --date "2018-01-08)-$(date +%s --date "1999-12-28"))/(3600*24))) days
bash: command substitution: Zeile 4: Dateiende beim Suchen nach »"« erreicht.
bash: command substitution: Zeile 5: Syntaxfehler: Unerwartetes Dateiende.
> ^C
rosika@rosika-10159:~$ echo $?
130
```

The error messages are clear I think but I didn´t get my command prompt back. The system seems to have been waiting for something. Yet it´s not clear me for what.

I finally entered "CTRL+C" and so I got my command prompt back. **I hope I did the right thing there.**

The error code was "130". Well, it´s clear to me that it couldn´t be "0".

What I´d like to understand is: *what is it that the system could have been waiting for?*

Perhaps some of you knowledgeable folks could shed some light on the matter?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Many greetings.
Rosika

P.S.:

my system: Linux/Lubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: It's waiting for a complete command - see related [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the explanation and the link. So it´s waiting for the completion of a string with the closing inverted commas. Tnx again.

Answer (score 0):

The shell was waiting for the closing double quote and twice the closing `))`.

```bsh
$ echo $((($(date +%s --date "2018-01-08)-$(date +%s --date "1999-12-28"))/(3600*24))) days" )) ))
date: invalid date ‘2018-01-08)-946335600)/(3600*24))) days’
bash: () : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") ")
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Hi @choroba Thank you for explaining. Instead of cutting short the sequence with "CTRL+C" could I simply have entered the second inverted commas manually and would my command then have been executed?

Comment: And what happened when you tried it? You can type `" )) ))` and press `Enter` again, so the shell can throw the syntax error.

Comment: Hi. Following up your suggestion and typing `" )) ))` after entering the faulty command I get the following: `date: invalid date ‘2018-01-08)-946335600)/(3600*24))) days\n’
bash: () : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ") ")`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I've shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think everything´s clear now. Many greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Your command contains a syntax error : missing double quote at second date call :

`--date "2018-01-08`

```
user@host:~$ echo $((($(date +%s --date "2018-01-08")-$(date +%s --date "1999-12-28"))/(3600*24))) days
6586 days
```

Comment: Hi @cmak.fr Thanks for confirming that. But what coud I have done in that case except of cancelling with "CTRL+C"?

Comment: CTRL+D  ... ;) nothing else than exiting

Comment: Hi again. I see. So it´s either "CTRL+C" or "CTRL+D". Glad to learn I did the right thing. Thanks a lot for your help.