# Unable to run git command (with ~/.bashrc modified)

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, environment-variables, git

I'm using powershell in Windows to clone a repository to an on-premise Ubuntu GPU environment (specifically, NVIDIA-DGX). After successfully ssh, I followed instructions and added the following codes at the end part of **~/.bashrc**:

```
# Enable https clone in dgx
export https_proxy=
export http_proxy=
```

After that I ran the following commands:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache`
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=2592000'

# Initialize git lfs
git lfs install

# Clone respository
git clone <HTTPS_GIT_URL>
```

However, the expected prompt asking for username and password didn't show and powershell simply didn't react, the situation is like this:

[image: img_Powershell]

Is it because the **http_proxy** filed should not be null? Or the git commands are wrong? Thx.

Comment: Are the https_proxy and http_proxy supposed to be set to something?  That export will actually do nothing.  If you run `echo $https_proxy` after that command it will return nothing.

Comment: Where did you get these commands? They're either broken or badly formatted.

Comment: ... in particular, the unmatched backtick in the first `git config` command is dropping your shell to the `PS2` prompt. See for example [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)

Comment: @steeldriver submit an answer. You just answered completely in your comment... maybe (doubtful, but who knows) it'll get accepted

Comment: @steeldriver A big thanks to you! Just found that it's due to backstick.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for pointing out. Will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver) for pointing out the problem of backtick on the comment.

Yes, after removing the line:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache`
```

The problem is solved.

Actually, I have found that this line is even not necessary given I already have:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=2592000'
```

<sub>Note: Answer provided by OP on question</sub>