# Ubuntu Server - Cannot copy file

Tags: command-line, server, copy

Why I can't copy "Change Your Life's Direction" book? How should I be copying this file?

[image: screenshot]

Please help. I'm a beginner.

Comment: have you tried running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: yeah, but failed

Comment: The problem is likely the single quote characters (apostrophes) `'`. I'd suggest omitting the backslashes and surrounding the whole name in double quotes instead. See also [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)

Comment: wow, thanks it solved