# Terminal shows A GREATER Symbol ">" after I run this command

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg

When I type in the command in the terminal it gives me this, a greater symbol.  What should I do now, and what does it mean?

`>`

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mbmX.png)

Here is The Command I Used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v  minterpolate='mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:fps=60:me=ds'" out.mp4
```

Comment: You have an unbalanced quote `"` - see [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've either lost a double quote or you've found one, so the shell is showing you its `$PS2`. Try deleting the `"` at the end.

Comment: Oh wow thanks for finding that that mistake, what a big help