# How do I get my terminal working after clicking ' enter accidentally?

Tags: xubuntu

[image]

I can't enter commands on my terminal.
All I get is

```
>
>
>
```

Comment: Press CTRL+C to break out of that.

Comment: See also [What mode does the terminal go into when I type a single quote?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890782/what-mode-does-the-terminal-go-into-when-i-type-a-single-quote)