# I renamed the directory "Video's" into "Video_s", to avoid complications in Terminal, but a new problem came up

Tags: directory, bookmarks

I work with a Lubuntu 22.04 LTS installation on a laptop set for the Duch locale.

Because I experienced a problem when copying a file in Terminal from my "Video's" directory (see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450542/in-terminal-i-get-a-symbol-when-i-try-to-copy-a-large-video-screen-capture-t)), I changed the name of that directory to "Video_s", which solved that problem. But a new problem arose.

First: the name "Video's" for the directory/folder in my  user-directory stems from my locale setting, because in the Dutch language the plural of video is video's.

The problem that I encountered after changing the directory name to "Video_s" is illustrated by the attached picture.
When I selected my user folder in the GUI I saw that the folder for Videos still was named "Video's" and when I selected that "Video's" folder I got the error as can be seen in the illustration: "Error when getting information for file “/home/paul/Video's”: No such file or directory".

[image]

So, I renamed that GUI folder by right-clicking on it and selecting "change bookmark name" (it was in Dutch, but this is the equivalent in English I guess) and I changed "Video's" there also into "Video_s".

Alas, that did not solve it, because when clicking this changed Video_s-folder, I got the same error as before: "Error when getting information for file “/home/paul/Video's”: No such file or directory".

[image]

As can be seen the content of the directory "Video_s", does not appear while the directory "Video_s" is not empty, as I can assure you.

Now I suppose that the GUI-folder, now named "Video_s" being a bookmark according to the systeem, still points to the old "Video's" directory which does not exist anymore, but I do not know how to change this behavior of that bookmark.

Who can tell me how to do that?

Comment: Edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`.

Comment: I changed the entry in to XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Video_s"

Comment: @Jos The above comment broke off because I edited too long. What I needed to say is that the path above the window now still shows the path /home/paul/Video's and no content appears in the window, so more needs to be done.

Comment: For the moment I decided to change everything back to "Video's" because I rather use escapes for my copying then that I am stuck with incompatibilities within my system. Also my backups have "Video's" in them and I am afraid that restoring from such a backup will mess things up further. But I am still open for suggestions to a solution of course.

Comment: Why does "Video's" have an apostrophe in it?

Comment: @Organic Marble It is Dutch, explained in the question.